# Syntactic Complexity Class ${\bf X}$ such that ${\bf PP} \subseteq {\bf X} \subseteq {\bf PSPACE}$

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes

It is known that some (non-relativized) syntactic complexity classes between ${\bf P}$ and ${\bf PSPACE}$ have the following property, ${\bf P} \subseteq {\bf CoNP} \subseteq {\bf US} \subseteq {\bf C_=P} \subseteq {\bf PP} \subseteq {\bf PSPACE}$. I am wondering if there exists a (non-relativized) syntactic complexity class ${\bf X}$ such that ${\bf PP} \subseteq {\bf X} \subseteq {\bf PSPACE}$? What are the implications of existence or non-existence of complexity class ${\bf X}$ ?

Comment: First, presumably you want a class which is believed to lie *strictly* between PP and PSPACE? Otherwise PP itself works, as does PSPACE. Second, it's difficult to talk about the implications of the existence of such a complexity class unless you specify what counts as a complexity class. For example, if PP \neq PSPACE, then by Ladner there is a language L in PSPACE that is PP-hard and not PSPACE-complete. If we take the closure of L under many-one reductions, the resulting "class" satisfies your question. But clearly this has no additional consequences beyond PP \neq PSPACE...

Comment: @JoshuaGrochow Thanks! How about if ${\bf P} = {\bf PP}$ but ${\bf P} \neq {PSPACE}$. Can we get another class by Ladner?

Comment: Yes. Same thing. Ladner's construction is very general: for any two languages $A \lneq_m^p B$ it gives a language $A \lneq_m^p C \lneq_m^p B$.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One such class is the *counting hierarchy* $\mathsf{CH}$. It is defined as the union of a hierarchy that is defined similarly to the polynomial hierarchy:

- $\mathsf{C}_{0}\mathsf{P} := \mathsf{PP}$,
- $\mathsf{C}_{i+1}\mathsf{P} := \mathsf{PP}^{\mathsf{C}_{i}\mathsf{P}}$
- $\mathsf{CH} := \bigcup_i \mathsf{C}_{i}\mathsf{P}$

The counting hierarchy has a nice syntactic characterization due to 
[H. Vollmer and K. Wagner "Recursion theoretic characterizations of complexity classes of counting functions", Theoretical Computer Science 163:245-258, 1996](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0304-3975%2895%2900237-5):
$\mathsf{CH}$ ist the set of $0$-$1$-valued functions in the closure of basic arithmetic functions $0,1,+,-,\cdot$ under composition and bounded sums.

Comment: I specifically say non-relativized... There is also ${\bf\#P} \cup {\bf \#NP} \cup ... $

Comment: @TayfunPay: The final paragraph shows that $CH$ can be given a characterization without the use of oracles...what, precisely, do you mean by "non-relativized" then? Do you want a "non-oracle machine" characterization"? A leaf language characterization?

Comment: It is indeed correct. Ok